# Is there a name for the extra factor in the small-population proportion estimation?

Tags: statistics, terminology, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Different formulas are generally presented for estimation of a population proportion in the large-population versus small-population cases. For example, looking at the [Penn State](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/6) website:

Section 6.2 - Estimating a Proportion for a Large Population:
[image: Confidence interval for proportion, large population]

Section 6.3 - Estimating a Proportion for a Small, Finite Population:
[image: Confidence interval for proportion, small population]

I'm wondering if there's a specific **English language name** for that extra factor of $\frac {N - n} {N - 1}$ in the small-population case?

(By way of analogy, I'm looking for something similar to the name [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) for use of $n - 1$ in the sample standard deviation formula to get an unbiased estimator there.)

Comment: I don't know about a name, but that looks like the hypergeometric distribution variance.

Comment: It is a finite population correction (fpc) factor.